# MVC kendo grid with nested detail grid erroring on enabling editability

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have an editable kendo grid, which has a detail section containing some text, and another grid. The nested grid works fine as far as I can tell when it is outside of the template with editing enabled, and works fine inside the template with editing disabled. However, as soon as editing is enabled, either via adding .ediable, a toolbar with create, or a command.edit / command.destroy, it will immediately fail to render with an invalid template error.

Relevant code for the grid. it is able to access the #=id# variable just fine

```
 <text>Headers</text>
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<eCurriculumAdminJunior.Models.Feedback.SectionHeader>()
    .Name("SectionHeaderGrid#=id#")
    .Columns(col =>
    {
        col.Bound(c => c.position).Hidden(true);
        col.Bound(c => c.text).EditorTemplateName("RichText").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 60%" });
        col.Bound(c => c.viewableby).Title("Visibility").EditorTemplateName("VisibleTo").ClientTemplate("#=ArrayToString(data.viewableby)#").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 30%" });
        col.Command(command =>
        {
            command.Edit().IconClass("glyphicon glyphicon-edit").Text(" ").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-decoration: none" });
            //command.Destroy().IconClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle").Text(" ").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-decoration: none" });
        }).Width("5em").Title(" ");
    })
    .ToolBar(t =>
    {
        t.Create();
    })
    .Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .DataSource(ds => ds.Ajax()
    .Model(m =>
    {
        m.Id(id => id.id);
        m.Field(f => f.id).DefaultValue(-1);

    })
    .Batch(false)
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .Read(r => r.Action("ReadSectionHeader", "FeedbackForm", new { sectionID = "#=id#" }))
    .Update(u => u.Action("UpdateSectionHeader", "FeedbackForm"))
    .Create(c => c.Action("CreateSectionHeader", "FeedbackForm",new { sectionID = "#=id#" }))
    .Destroy(d => d.Action("DeleteSectionHeader", "FeedbackForm"))
    ).ToClientTemplate()
)
<text>Content</text>
```